# wget download after auth form with redirect

Tags: javascript, cookies, download, wget

I'm having an issue trying to download an image... in specific, I need to download from this URL (also changing get parameters)

https://www.mercatoelettrico.org/it/Esiti/MGP/DomandaOfferta.aspx?zona=nord&data=20140918&ora=12

but the web site is redirecting me to

https://www.mercatoelettrico.org/It/Tools/Accessodati.aspx...

(that has a javascript onsubmit) downloading that page instead of my image. I followed many guides I found but still I can't figure out how to download that image.

One of my last trials was this... trying to save a cookie to avoid the auth in the following connections, but the cookie stays empty

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 
     --content-disposition 
     --no-check-certificate 
     --save-cookies cookies.txt 
     --post-data "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBAccetto1=on&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBAccetto2=on&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1=Accetto" 
     "https://www.mercatoelettrico.org/it/Tools/Accessodati.aspx"
```

dunno what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--keep-session-cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

The login cookie is *almost* always a session cookie. A special kind of cookie which is not supposed to persist beyond your current browsing session and hence Wget discards those cookies without saving them.

However, the use case that you've explained is also pretty common, which is why there is a special switch, `--keep-session-cookies` which will force Wget to store the session cookies to the cookies.txt file too.

In your next invokation remember to load the cookies.txt file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Now it stores some information in the cookie file but still it redirects me on the page "...Tools/AccessoDati..." downloading that beautifully useless page. I think my problem could be the auth process cos it uses some kind of javascript. Is there a method to bypass this?